# fzf to return combination of input fields

Tags: bash, fzf

I have this command:

```bash
echo -e "a 1 10\nb 2 20\nc 3 30\nd 4 40" | fzf -m --bind 'enter:execute(echo {1}:{2})+abort' | tr -d "'"
```

Input data looks like:

```
a 1 10
b 2 20
c 3 30
d 4 40
```

How do I modify fzf part to return space separated strings in format of `{1}:{2}` but for all selections? Expected output result (if we select lines begining with `a` and `b`) is:

```
a:1 b:2
```

I tried changing fzf placeholder to `{+1}:{+2}` but it first echoes all first fields and then all second fields instead of combining them.

Thank you.

Comment: @jhnc ok, it achieves the end goal so I may as well use awk instead of fzf for the formatting. Thank you very much - post it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the fzf manual, I don't see much functionality for formatting its output.

As your data seems to be whitespace-delimited fields, it is quite easy to postprocess `fzf`'s output:

```
# space between results, no terminator
... | fzf -m | awk '$0=(NR>1?" ":"")$1":"$2' ORS=

# space after each result
... | fzf -m | awk NF=2 OFS=: ORS=" "

# space between results, newline terminator
... | fzf -m | awk NF=2 OFS=: | xargs
```